# No module named 'apt_pkg'

Tags: 16.04

i am trying to download R studio into my device. i am trying following commands,

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core

wget https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb

sudo gdebi -n rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb

rm rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb
```

when i try,

```
sudo gdebi -n rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb
```

i get error

`No module named 'apt_pkg'`

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add output of `which python` and `which python3` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the problem with `apt_pkg` python module by (re)installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-apt python3-apt
```

Then you have to install RStudio deb-file as you have already tried from the folder where it is located with:

```
wget https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi -n rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb
```

or using apt-get directly:

```
sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb
```

as it allows single deb-file installation in recent versions and it will satisfy the dependencies automatically.

Comment: i did what you mentioned above, but i get the same error : No module named 'apt_pkg'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it via gdebi, try installing it directly via dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb
```

You don't have to delete rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb file afterwards.

Run this command from the directory which contains the rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb file. You may have deleted it (from the commands posted in the question), so be sure to check that the file exists, and if it doesn't download it again using the wget command.

Comment: sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb

 

it also return error

Comment: @user1120 Give the full path to the rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb as the argument to dpkg -i. Also make sure the deb file is there, because you deleted it first with the rm command. In that case, download using wget and the use this command.

Comment: The `dpkg -i rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb` will not resolve the dependencies; the `sudo apt-get install -f` will be needed after it. Use `sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb` instead.